# Failed to Fetch data value on Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

My goal is to get data value right when it change on Firebase Database using `onChildChanged` function or `addChildEventListener` function.

This is the error code. The log shows "Value is null"

//My `ref` is `child("userID").child(id).child("Personal Information");`

```
databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        String key = dataSnapshot.child("name").getKey().toString();
        String value = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
        if (value != null) {
            Log.i("FirebaseDataChange", "Key: "+ key + " Value: " + value);
         } else {
            Log.e("FirebaseDataChange", "Value is null");
         }
    }
    ...
```

Things have tried :

- Instead of the dataSnapshot.child("name") . I used child("address") and it works, the value can fetched successfully. I did a bit of research and found out that right when the data changed the value will be null. I don't why but it's null. I don't know how to fix this.
- Check reference path. I'm sure it's the right path.
- Remove the "String key "line. Add toString() to the value initialized line
- Tried using addEventlistener function and the data did not become null WHEN FETCH after change. But I want to fix the old code.

Comment: There is certainly no data at the location of the database you're trying to access.  Since we can't see your database, we don't know what you're doing wrong.  Please edit the question to show the contents so we can see if your query matches your data.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.